# How to get checked items data and count from ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, checkbox, expandablelistview

I want to show the count and all the data when clicked. But so far in testing using click on the Parent item

I tried increment `checkedCount` when check. But it show only checked count in in one group child elemements.

**My Adapter:**

```
public class RubExpandAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<RubricsModel> rubrics;
private List<VacancyModel> listForRubricListView;
private List<VacancyModel> listForSubRubricListView;
private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;
public static int rubricPage = 1;
public static int rubricId;
public static int subRubricPage = 1;
public static int subRubricId;
int checkedCount;
FragmentManager fm;

public RubExpandAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RubricsModel> rubrics, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rubrics = rubrics;
    fm = fragmentManager;
    listForRubricListView = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<SubRubricsModel> chList = rubrics.get(groupPosition)
            .getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    final int mChildPosition = childPosition;
    SubRubricsModel subRubricsModel = (SubRubricsModel) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.rubrics_child_row_layout, null);
    }
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvsubrubricsfr);
    tv.setText(subRubricsModel.getSubRubricName());

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
        }
    });

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
            } else {
                boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mChildCheckStates.size(); i++){
                if (mChildCheckStates.containsValue(true)){
                    checkedCount ++;
                }
            }

        }
    });

    if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {
        boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
        checkBox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);

    } else {
        boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];

        mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<SubRubricsModel> chList = rubrics.get(groupPosition)
            .getItems();

    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return rubrics.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return rubrics.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final RubricsModel rubricsModel = (RubricsModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.rubrics_group_row_layout, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvrubricsfr);
    tv.setText(rubricsModel.getRubricName());
    ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGroupIndicator);

    if (isExpanded) {
        indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);

    } else {
        indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_right);
    }

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//                RubFragment.searchByRubrics = true;
//                rubricId = rubricsModel.getRubricID();
//                searchByRubric(String.valueOf(rubricId));
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(mChildCheckStates.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

how to do, tell me, pls?